# Use .so files with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, .so

I'm trying to submit and use a python module through pyspark, but I'm stuck at an import error. Everything works perfectly in local but the problem rises when submitting the job to remote workers.

The module I'm trying to use has an import statement to some **.so** files which are functions that I've created compiling fortran code with f2py. I've tried to submit all the files in a .zip with the sc.addFile(.zip) command and also with the sc.addPyFile(.zip). In this way I can access all the .py files but I can't find the .so files. The same happens by manually listing all files and also with the --files command when using spark-submit.

Is there any way I can send also the .so files to use? Or maybe, since I've a Makefile, can I compile them on the remote machines?

Since the hole package isn't very heavy is it possible to copy it on the remote machine and then tell pyspark to access that folder?

The remote machines are connected via ssh so I can send and move files there.
The files structure looks like this:

```
.
├── libs
│   ├── FortranFunctions.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
│   ├── libCPU.py
│   ├── libGPU.py
│   └── lib.py
├── LICENSE
├── main.py
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── src
│   └── FortranFunctions.f90
└── variables.py
```

As you can see in the /libs folder I've placed some .py files that are accessible when using spark and the .so file that I' cannot import.

As requested I add the codes:

The File fortranFunctions.f90 in src/ folder is the source code of my fortran subroutines that I use in python.

The code in python is just `from libs import FortranFunctions` and this **locally** works.

The code used to submit the job looks like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from main import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('pySiPM').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

sc.addFile('files.zip')

data = []
for i in range(20):
    times = np.ones(np.random.poisson(5))*30
    data.append(times)

res = sc.parallelize(data).map(SiPM).collect()
```

Comment: Where's the code??

Comment: I've added the code used to launch the spark job